# Proving that if $n$ is odd, then $n^2=8k+1 \text{ for some } k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm currently studying Lay's *Analysis with an introduction to Proofs*.

I am trying to prove this statement:

If $n$ is odd, then there exists a $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n^2=8k+1$

I first started by saying that $n$ is odd, then it can be written as $n=2m+1$ for $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Substituting this in, I find that 
$$4m^2+4m+1=8k+1$$
$$m^2+m=2k$$
$$m(m+1)=2k$$
I now just need to show that $m(m+1)\text{ for } m\in\mathbb{N}$ is even, which I am not sure how to rigorously prove.

Is it enough to say: if $m$ is odd, then $m+1$ is even, thus their product is even; if $m$ is even, then $m+1$ is odd, and their product is once again even? Their product is even because multiplying a number that is divisible by $2$ with any integer yields a product that $2$ still divides.

How can I improve my argument?

Comment: What you are doing is indeed enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, what you are doing is sufficient. Since you are new to proofs, I figured I would write out the proof in a logical order.

Since $n$ is odd, there exists a non-negative integer $m$ such that $n = 2m+1$. Furthermore, (by your argument), there exists another non-negative integer $k$ such that $m(m+1) = 2k$. Now, we may write
$$
n^2 = 4m^2+4m+1 = 4m(m+1)+1 = 4(2k)+1 = 8k+1
$$

Comment: Thank you! So are you saying that my proof is essentially backwards, or a pre-proof that I can use to construct a logical proof like yours?

Comment: Exactly. It's a pre-proof that you can use to construct a logical proof

Comment: Can I ask why your proof is considered more logical? I just see them as two different ways of arriving at the same result.

Comment: Yours is just as logical. The only "advantage" of what I wrote is that it starts with the assumption and ends with the conclusion. Specifically, in your proof you wrote "4m^2+4m+1=8k+1" before showing it was true for some integer $k$. To be clear, your proof is perfectly fine. But, it's good habit to write proofs starting with the assumptions and ending at the conclusions. When the proofs get long it becomes hard to follow otherwise

Comment: Alright, I understand now! So I started with the conclusion and then showed that the assumption was true.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct.

You may consider $n=4m\pm1$. The proof will be a bit shorter.

Answer (score 0):

**hint:** Consider mod $4$, $n = 4k+1$ since it's an odd integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just say that, within two consecutive numbers, there'll always be one even. Thus, $m\cdot(m+1)$ is an even number that can be written as $2k$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

just consider the 2 cases for m. m can be even or m can be odd. so for case 1 let m=2x and plug that into the equation and you get an even number. case 2 let m=2x+1 and plug into the equation and you get an even number again. so for both cases the number is even and therefore proven.