# If $n$ is odd, then there is an integer $k$ such that $n^2=8k+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility, solution-verification, integers

I'm learning how to make rigorous proofs and I'm currently trying to prove this result:

**Proposition:** Let $n$ be an odd integer. Then there exists an integer $k$ such that $n^2=8k+1$.

I already prove the following result:

**Propostion:** Let $n$ be an integer. Then $n^2+n$ is an even integer.

So my proof is:

Let $n$ be an odd integer. Then there exists an integer $j$ such that $n=2j+1$. Then
$n^2=(2j+1)^2=4j^2+4j+1=4(j^2+j)+1$
By the proposition stated, since $j$ is an integer, then $j^2+j$ is even. Then there exists an integer $k$ such that $j^2+j=2k$. Then $n^2=4(2k)+1=8k+1$. Hence there is an integer $k$ such that $n^2=8k+1$

---

I searched for different proofs and I found this one here: [Proving that if $n$ is odd, then $n^2=8k+1 \text{ for some } k\in\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2704219)

I realized I could state that there exists an integer $k$ such that $2k=m(m+1)$. By substituting, we can conclude that $n^2=8k+1$. In terms of logic, what should be our approach to take this proof? Why can't we solve the equation to find that $2k=m(m+1)$? Thank you!

Comment: Your argument looks good, though you omit the (trivial) proof that $n^2+n=n(n+1)$ is always even.   Not sure what else you are asking.

Comment: if $n=7$, then $n^2=49$ and so $49=8*6+1$ so $k=6$

Comment: What is your question ? How to prove that $2k=m(m+1)$ for some $k$ if $m$ is an integer ? This is obvious because one of $m$ and $m+1$ is even.

Comment: @lulu I don't know why  but the proof in the link above it doesn't seem right to me, what do you think? Thank you!

Comment: @Andrew you probably wanted to write $(j^2 + j) = 2k$ instead of $j = 2k$, right?

Comment: @araomis thank you  that's correct :)

Comment: @Peter this was my proof, but the proof in the link seems strange to me. I want to know why the proof in the link is valid

Comment: I see no problem with the argument in the link.  Indeed, to see that $n^2+n=n(n+1)$ is always even it is natural to go by cases. Either $n$ is even in which case we are immediately done, or $n$ is odd in which case $n+1$ is even and again we are done.

Comment: @lulu hum I'm understanding, but when we state that $2k=m(m+1)$ we **have** to prove that $m(m+1)$ is even right?

Comment: Yes, I'd say that was worth a proof...but the linked argument supplies that proof.  Presumably the proof you have for your second proposition was more or less the same as that one, no?

Comment: Side note:  if you want an argument that, at least, feels a little different, note that every odd number $n$  must be either of the form $n=4k+1$ or the form $n=4k-1$.  Now verify the claim for both cases separately.

Comment: @lulu yes, it was the same idea, supposing that n is even and concluding that n+1 is odd and if n is odd then n+1 is even

Comment: @lulu thank you for your last suggestion! I'm going to work on that argument! :)

Comment: Variation of the same argument, $(n^2-1)=(n-1)(n+1)$ is product of two even numbers which differ by $2$, so exactly one of them will be divisible by $4$, so the product is divisible by $2\cdot 4=8$.